# Read file in blocks

Tags: python, for-loop, readline

I'm having an issue which I'm currently stuck on.

I have a big file in the following format:

## Block 1

```
Line 1: Something/Type2
Line 2: Time
Line 3: Data we need
Line 4: 00.*
Line 5: Fix 100
Line 6: In..
Line 7: Ou..
Line 8: Data we need
Line 9: Next
Line 10: Multi_Exit
```

## Block 2

```
Line 1: Something/Type1
Line 2: Time
Line 3: Data we need
Line 4: 00.*
Line 5: Fix 100
Line 6: In..
Line 7: Ou..
Line 8: Data we need
Line 9: Next
Line 10: Multi_Exit
```

## Block 3

```
Line 1: Something/Type1
Line 2: Time
Line 3: Data we need
Line 4: 00.*
Line 5: Fix 100
Line 6: In..
Line 7: Ou..
Line 8: Data we need
Line 9: Next
Line 10: Multi_Exit
```

## Block 4

```
Line 1: Type1/Type2
Line 2: Time
Line 3: Data we need
Line 4: 00.*
Line 5: Fix 100
Line 6: In..
Line 7: Ou..
Line 8: Data we need
Line 9: Next
Line 10: Multi_Exit
```

## Etc

I want to read the first line of each block, to check if Type1 or Type2. After this I want to print Line 3 and Line 8 of each block and keep on doing that until file ends.

I have tried the following codes:

```
p = './file.txt'
fin = open(p, 'r')

for i, line in enumerate(fin):
if i%11 == 2 or i%11 == 7:
    print line
fin.close()
```

I have noticed after this code is run on my big file the line changes. I can only assume my block lengths isn't fixed to 10 lines (plus one line space before the next block starts). So this method isn't ideal.

I have also tried regular expression but I'm having trouble storing my results on the format I want such as:

```
For Type 1
```

File the output should be:
    Line 3: Data Line 8: Data

Single space between it.

This is the next code I have tried:

```
for line in fin:
if re.match("(Line 1|Line 3|Line 8)", line):
    writeToFile(line)
```

Where writeToFile function does the following:

```
def writeToFile(filein):
    p = './output.txt'
    fo = open(p, 'a')
    fo.write(filein)
    fo.close()
```

This is how the output.txt file looks:

```
Line 1: Something/Type2

Line 3: Data we need

Line 8: Data we need


Line 1: Something/Type1

Line 3: Data we need

Line 8: Data we need


Line 1: Something/Type1

Line 3: Data we need

Line 8: Data we need
```

Which is not exactly the desired outcome. I don't even mind to play around with this output file and check for Line 1 if Type 1. Then get Line 3 and Line 8 put them in the same line. Keep on doing that, until Type 2 is found and do the same with Line 3 and Line 8 and store it in different output file.

I hope I haven't complicated things.

Edit:

Sorry I was not clear and also made a mistake.

In Line 1: the first part before the / I'm not interested. I'm interested it after that which sometimes chances to Type1 or Type2.

Ideally the output should be, look for the Type in the first line, if Type2 output:

```
Line 1: Type2 Line 3: Data we need Line 8: Data we need
```

If Type1:

```
Line 1: Type1 Line 3: Data we need Line 8: Data we need
Line 1: Type1 Line 3: Data we need Line 8: Data we need
```

To group all the block which have the same type.

Edit:
I'm getting my desired output now thanks to user:Floris

If I feed it to my write to file function.

```
def writeToFile(type, outputString):
    p = './output'+type+'.txt'
    fo = open(p, 'a')
    line = '%s %s\n' % (type, outputString)
    fo.write(line)
    fo.close()
```

This is getting my results as:

```
Type2 Line 3: Data we need Line 8: Data we need
```

And

```
Type1 Line 3: Data we need Line 8: Data we need
Type3 Line 3: Data we need Line 8: Data we need
```

My writeToFile sorts it by type when I specify how to save it as type path.

Thank you

Comment: It would really help if you **showed** the exact output you want, instead of trying to **describe** it. For example, you said "File the output should be: Line 3: Data Line 8: Data".  That could mean several things.  In particular, from your last output it looks like you **also** want "Line 1:" lines in the output.  I'm lost ;-)

Comment: Let me try to paraphrase. For blocks where Line 1 says "type 1", you want to concatenate lines 3 and 8 and send to one file. For "type 2", you want to send to another file. How are "blocks" separated? With `#block` in a line by itself? Or by space? or...

Comment: I'm trying to build a table depending on the Type I find in Line 1: but the format I output should be the same like Line 1: Type1(or Type2) Line 3: Data we need Line 8: Data we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the following code gives you the inspiration you need to solve your problem - I bet it does:

```
import re
fin = open("./file.txt")

for line in fin:
    if re.match("Line 1:", line):
      # note we need to match "Line 1:" (including colon) so we don't match "Line 10"
      m = re.match(".*Type(.)", line)
      type = m.group(1)
      # we now know what type this group is
    if re.match("Line 3:", line):
      m = re.match(".*3:(.*)$", line)
      outputString = m.group(1)
      # have first half of output string
    if re.match("Line 8:", line):
      m = re.match(".*8:(.*)$", line)
      outputString += m.group(1)
      # have second half of output string, and we know where it needs to go:
      print "concatenated string of type ", type," is ", outputString
      # now send it where you want it to go... one of two open files, perhaps?

fin.close()
```

Comment: I have made a mistake when showing the data on Line 1 as I have edited this. Sorry for this. Line 1 is like Line 1: Something/Type1(or Type2). Is there a way to look what comes after the "/" and if group all those together and if this changes to Type2 then group these together? I like your output as this is what I had in mind. I have tried to put a "/" instead of your example Type and try to put another If loop?

Comment: You can just leave out the space before `Type`: `m = re.match(".*Type(.)", line)` should do it. In my test file I had `Type1/Type2` (copied from your example) and I wanted to find "the first number" which is why I added the space in the first place. If `Something` never includes the characters `Type` then this will work. I will edit the answer accordingly.